# TToolBar: how to get rid of vertical bars?

Tags: delphi, toolbar, delphi-xe

When I have a TToolbar and I put non-toolbutton controls on it, there is a superfluous vertical bar through the control. How can I get rid of the bar?

In the image below, the toolbar contains only two toolbuttons and a TLabel and no separators. Notice the vertical bar through the letter V.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, this is due to the handle of transparency of other non TToolButton controls that are placed in the TToolBar and, for this reason, if you set "Transparent" property of your TLabel to false, the vertical bar will disappear.

Comment: There are some controls that just can't look good directly placed on a TToolbar, so for that reason, if I'm using a mix of toolbar buttons and non-toolbar controls, I just put all those controls on a TPanel and forget about using the TToolbar. Remember to test with all possible Windows theme/appearances if you decide to use TToolbar.

Comment: This helps. Unsetting transparent of a control has the small side effect of the control being, ehm... not transparent anymore. I think I'll use the suggestion of Warren, but then I lose the nice gradient I like the TToolBar for. Thanks.

Comment: @Arnold you could always override the paint procedure of the TPanel to draw a gradient yourself, or look for a 3rd party gradient panel component.

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/toolbar/flattoolbar/article.php/c2561/Hiding-the-Flat-Toolbar-Separators.htm - CPP implementation of own drawing

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try JVCL component suites (free) [Delphi Jedi](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/). It has a lot of visual components, including all sorts of panels & buttons. They also have panel with gradient colors, and image buttton for examples.

Comment: I'll dive deeper into JVCL when I can get it installed :-) Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I installed Jedi and it indeed has a large amount of controls, like the Gradient component. Very useful, thanks for pointing it out to me!

Comment: You are welcome @Arnold. I feel that some components are just beyond my imagination :) But at least it provides me with all sorts of ideas, comes with source code and free as well.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi XE2 Hot Update 4, Still got this bug, i work around this bug by :

1. Setting TLabel.Autosize := False;
2. TLabel.width := 50; --> just make sure its more than its caption, at least by 10 pixels
3. TLabel.Alignment := taRightJustify

Thanks.