# Delphi TToolBar Superfluous Vertical Bar in tbsSeparator

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I'm using Delphi XE6 on top of Windows 2012 R2, and trying to create applications with toolbars.  I'm however experiencing problems with the compiled application having a vertical superfluous bar at the left hand side of any Separators I might add.

This problem is described in both [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113781/delphi-tbsseparator-ttoolbutton-on-a-non-themed-ttoolbar-with-flat-style-has-a-v) and [This Other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777219/ttoolbar-how-to-get-rid-of-vertical-bars), however I am not trying to use any other fancy controls - I am solely using the "New Button" and "New Separator" to add items.  I have nonetheless tried the suggested fixes to no avail.

My sample application has been created as follows:

1. New VCL Forms Application
2. Add TToolBar
3. Select ToolBar1
4. Right Click, Select "New Button"
5. Right Click, Select "New Button"
6. Right Click, Select "New Separator"
7. Right Click, Select "New Button"
8. Run

This is what the application looks like

[image: Superfluous Bar]

I have tried changing every potentially applicable property of the TToolBar itself (including setting Transparent to False), as well as the ToolBar3 (which is set to tbsSeparator), but I cannot seem to get rid of this vertical bar.  I have also tried to add a TXPManifest to the form, but this made no difference.

The only thing that does seem to make a difference is if I set the Separator Visible property to False - the line disappears, but so does the Separator, so this isn't any help.

The issue I'm experiencing is also described in [This thread](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.vcl.components.using/201201/1201138796.html), and I can assure the readers that I've not made any changes to the width of the Separator - it's all default.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

For what it's worth - my Delphi Form is like this - you can see that I'm not using any fancy controls other than the supported ones:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 112
  ClientWidth = 382
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ToolBar1: TToolBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 382
    Height = 29
    Caption = 'ToolBar1'
    TabOrder = 0
    Transparent = False
    object ToolButton1: TToolButton
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'ToolButton1'
      ImageIndex = 0
    end
    object ToolButton2: TToolButton
      Left = 23
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'ToolButton2'
      ImageIndex = 1
    end
    object ToolButton3: TToolButton
      Left = 46
      Top = 0
      Width = 8
      Caption = 'ToolButton3'
      ImageIndex = 2
      Style = tbsSeparator
    end
    object ToolButton4: TToolButton
      Left = 54
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'ToolButton4'
      ImageIndex = 3
    end
  end
  object XPManifest1: TXPManifest
    Left = 40
    Top = 48
  end
end
```

Comment: Adding another manifest won't help. One is enough. This question is a dupe though. The fact that there is no clean solution doesn't mean that you can ask the question again. I asked the original question. I'd love it if there was a clean solution. But there isn't. Asking again won't change that reality. A themed separator has a left aligned vertical bar. That's unavoidable. That's the conclusion of the other topic.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I did not find your previous question, and I have been doing a lot of searching on the web.  I think I may however have a solution for both of us.   By using ActionToolBars (and of course, an action manager, which I always use anyway), you can create toolbars with icons with captions, icons without captions and dividers to do your icon grouping without the additional vertical bar issue cropping up.

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed that one of your linked questions was mine.

Answer (score 0):

As the `TToolbar` is a wrapper of Microsoft Windows `Rebar32 Control`, it looks exactly the same as a normal Windows application does. **Why not remove these separators, so that you will not see them anymore.**